# Do these pipes need to be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe, copper

We're remodeling a shower and after getting the tile and backer board off, this is what the pipes look like.

There isn't any noticeable leak, but it looks like maybe there was at some point? These pipes lead up to the valves and shower head which all look fine.

This is an older house, built circa 1970. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much oxidation on those pipes, especially on many of the joints, I would replace them, especially since you said the other pipes looked fine.This oxidation can corrode copper pipes. It doesn't look like a very competent person sweated those in the first place.

Comment: And they'll be leaded solder, given the era. Most of the corrosion is not cleaning off flux (which you really need to do if using one of the more aggressive types. The "Nokrorode®" brand exists for a reason...)

Comment: @Ecnerwal  And not a lot of solder wiping either.

Comment: I have to wonder if any of the sideways or upward-facing joints are partially plugged with excess solder, given the enthusiastic "more is better" drips running down from the downward-facing joints. You've no doubt seen my tale of the hot water with pressure, until it was turned on, which was eventually traced (when I got mad enough to start ripping the pipe run apart joint by joint) to an elbow that had less than 1/16" for water flow left in the vast plug of solder inside it.

Comment: I remember that tale... did you frame that elbow or at least keep it as a paper weight?

Comment: Hard to tell the size of those pipes (1/2" or 3/4") but once you buy your new shower valve you may have to change pipe sizes and layout anyway. Buy the valve first before you replumb as the valve build will dictate what pipe fittings (male or female) you buy and install.